# How to get a string from HttpResponse or render to a string in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, http, encoding, rendering

Currently, I have the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# ...
def prerender(js: json) -> str:
    # ...
    response = render(None, 'partial/name.html', context)
    return response.content.decode()
```

Is there a way in Django to render to a string rather than to the bytes of `HttpResponse`? Otherwise, how to get `HttpResponse` content as a string properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is almost in your question:

```py
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

return render_to_string("partial/home.html", context)
```

You can use this to render all kinds of templates, for emails and so on.